# How do I insert '*.txt ' to a string which is a filepath in python?

Tags: python, glob

I have a python code with these two line to parse a specific set of files to my function

```
Allfile = glob.glob(project1)
project1 ='./DDfiles/*.txt'
```

instead I want to add /*.txt to Allfile line and project1 should just be root path. How do i insert that Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

How about this one?

```py
all_file = [filename + ".txt" for filename in glob.glob(project1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me you simply want to do this?

```py
project1 = './DDfiles/'
all_files = glob.glob(project1 + '*.txt')
```

Answer (score 0):

An object-oriented approach using `pathlib` library allows you to use `with_suffix()` method and in addition, the path is now not a string but a Path object which makes it much easier to reference parts of the path:

```
from pathlib import Path

filenames = [<a list of filenames>]
z = [Path(i).with_suffix('.txt') for i in filenames]
```

Or if you know your original project directory then you can also use recursive glob method of pathlib to recursively find all required files:

```
f = 'my_folder'
z = [i.with_suffix('.txt') for i in list(Path(f).rglob('*'))]
```